# Codeigniter redirect is not working on live server but working in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter for my project. I have create a foreach loop and I want to redirect after end of the loop. It is working on localhost but not in live server. Here is my code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function my_function() {
    $config['upload_path'] = 'my_file_destination/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('text_file')) {

        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();


        function curl_load($number_url){
            curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $number_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $response;
        }

        $number_url = base_url()."my_file_destination/".$upload_data['file_name'];
        $file_content = curl_load($number_url);

        $mobileNO = explode(',', $file_content);
        $smsFormat = "Hello, this is a test message from LMS. Test Multiple sms. Let me know if you get it.";

        function httpGet($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $output;
        }

        $user = "my_username";
        $pass = "my_password";
        $sid = "api_key";
        $url = "my_sms_api";
        $SMSText = urlencode($smsFormat);
        $i = 1;
        foreach($mobileNO as $mobile_no){
            $mobile_no = '88'.$mobile_no;
            echo httpGet("my_sms_api/plain?user=$user&password=$pass&sender=$sid&SMSText=$SMSText&GSM=$mobile_no&type=longSMS&datacoding=1");

            $sms_data = array(
                'mobile_no' => $mobile_no ,
                'message'   => $SMSText ,
                'sms_date'  => date('d/m/Y')
            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_custom_sms', $sms_data);

            $i++;
        }

        if($i = count($mobileNO)+1){
            redirect('customsms/index');
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I tried another solution from stackoverflow, but couldn't get, where is the probleme.
Please help me.

Comment: You have checked that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your local server and restarted apache2 right?

Comment: yes. it is enable.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it but seems like this will work :

```
function redirect_to($location){
  header("Location: $location");
  exit;
}

if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
  //success
  redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

Don't define a default value for an argument and then check for it, just don't give it a default to begin with. Also remove the brackets in the Location: header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of redirect function's.

Then find the file which is addressed in log file and check if there is any space or any unused blank lines 'before and after the php tag .If you find any space then remove it.
then your redirect function would be work.